# Can I travel to Austria if I got vaccinated recently?

Tags: covid-19, regulations, austria

The latest travel rules to go to Austria, as of today, say something like this: you can enter in the country as long you have one of these proofs:

1. Vaccination certificate + negative PCR test, or
2. Vaccination certificate + third booster dose
3. Confirmation of a recent COVID infection + negative PCR test

The above is the summary of the travel regulations from [mae.ro](https://www.mae.ro/travel-conditions/3670#801) – you can find a similar one [here](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/news/austria-to-apply-stricter-travel-rules-starting-from-monday/).

Now, here is my dillema: I got vaccinated recently, hence cannot take the booster dose.

Theoretically I should do the PCR test, but I am wondering if there an exception for this case (recent vaccination)?

---

At least, I would expect that the booster dose is to increase the immunity after `x` months, but being freshly vaccinated, I would expect I already have a good enough protection.

Not sure if it matters, I will travel by car.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no exception from the testing or isolation requirements for recently vaccinated persons who wish to enter Austria.

The negative test is only exempted for people who received a further dose 120 days after their complete administration (the second dose for most vaccines, or the first dose of J&J, or the first dose after a recovery).

https://www.oesterreich.gv.at/en/themen/coronavirus_in_oesterreich/pre-travel-clearance.html

From the [regulations](https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/GeltendeFassung.wxe?Abfrage=Bundesnormen&Gesetzesnummer=20011574):

> § 2. (1) Nachweise über eine geringe epidemiologische Gefahr im Sinne
> dieser Verordnung sind:   [...]
>
> 3. Impfnachweise über eine Impfung gegen COVID-19 mit einem in Anlage C angeführten Impfstoff, wenn folgende Voraussetzungen vorliegen:
>
> a) Zweitimpfung, wobei diese nicht länger als 270 Tage zurückliegen
> darf und zwischen dieser und der Erstimpfung mindestens 14 Tage
> verstrichen sein müssen,
>
> b) Ablauf von 21 Tagen seit der Impfung bei Impfstoffen, bei denen nur
> eine Impfung vorgesehen ist, wobei diese nicht länger als 270 Tage
> zurückliegen darf,
>
> c) Impfung, sofern mindestens 21 Tage davor ein positiver
> molekularbiologischer Test auf SARS-CoV-2 oder vor der Impfung ein
> Nachweis über neutralisierende Antikörper vorlag, wobei die Impfung
> nicht länger als 270 Tage zurückliegen darf, oder
>
> **d) weitere Impfung, wobei diese nicht länger als 270 Tage zurückliegen
> darf und zwischen dieser und einer Impfung gemäß lit. a oder c
> mindestens 120 Tage oder einer Impfung gemäß lit. b mindestens 14 Tage
> verstrichen sein müssen.**
>
> *§ 2.
> (1) Evidences of a low epidemiological risk under this
> Regulation are [...]*
>
> *3. Proof of vaccination against Covid-19 with a vaccine listed in Appendix C, if the following requirements are met:*
>
> *a) administration of the second dose, no more than 270 days ago, and at least 14 days must have elapsed between this and the administration of the first dose,*
>
> *b) expiry of 21 days after one dose administered no more than 270 days ago in the case of vaccines for
> which only one dose is scheduled*
>
> *c) administration of one dose, no more than 270 days ago, provided that there was
> a positive molecular biology test for SARS-CoV-2 at least 21 days prior to the administration, or evidence of
> neutralizing antibodies prior to vaccination;
> or*
>
> ***d) administration of a further dose, no more than 270 days ago and at least 120 days must have elapsed
> between this and the administration of the dose according to let. a or c, or at least 14 days must have elapsed between a vaccination according to let. b.***

the definitions applying to the exception

> § 9. (5) Die Verpflichtung nach dieser Verordnung, zusätzlich zu einem Impf- oder Genesungsnachweis ein negatives Testergebnis mitzuführen, gilt nicht für Personen, die über einen Nachweis **gemäß § 2 Abs. 1 Z 3 lit. d** verfügen.
>
> *(5) The obligation under this Regulation to have a negative test result in addition to a vaccination or recovery certificate does not apply to persons who have a certificate **under sec. 2, para. 1, no. 3, let. d**.*

Comment: Thanks for this! That made things clearer – however, is any particular reason why the booster/recover could eventually replace the need for PCR testing? I am wondering if that is mentioned anywhere.

Comment: @IonicăBizău I haven't been albe to find a rationale, other than the assumption they want you to give some incentative to take the third dose. Many pandemic regulations are not really rationally justified though (or maybe they were when initially drafted, but the final compromise makes it full of holes and contradictions)

Comment: @IonicăBizău (speaking from Germany), there is no scientific/factual reason behind a lot of covid restrictions anymore, but not having to always test yourself with at first the vaccine, then the booster is the popular carrot on a stick dangled in front of the population